# Solr extract substring from query

Tags: string, indexing, solr

I am new to **Solr** and I have had a difficult time with the following issue:

I am trying to extract from the following field, in the web interface, just the hour:

```
  "2016-08-15T10:28:03Z"
```

Is there a function, like in SQL, to extract the substring given a pattern?

Comment: you want to extract hour information only during search or during indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using PatternReplaceFilterFactory of solr.

you can get new field (say Hour) with hour value
 in the result set.

Example :

```
{
  "id":"1",
   "name":"iPhone",
   "date":"2016-08-15T10:28:03Z",
   "Hour":"10"
}
```

for this to work you have make some schema modification add new field with name of your choice(say Hour_dt).

```
<field name="Hour_dt"  type="H_date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

copy field from field which has date values "2016-08-15T10:28:03Z"(say date)

```
<copyField source="date" dest="Hour_dt"/>
```

for field definition refer below

```
<fieldType name="H_date" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" >
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\d+-\d+-\d+T" replacement="" replace="all" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern=":\d+:\d+Z" replacement="" replace="all" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Reindex data. you get Hour values for all documents which has date values.